# Como pausar videos en slider con onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando pausar los videos en mi slider pero no hay manera. alguien me puede echar una manilla gracias ;)

Dejo el codigo por aqui:

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);


// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */
  .slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  /* Next & previous buttons */
  .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -42px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
  }
  /* Position the "next button" to the right */
  .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
  .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);  
  }
  /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
  .dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  .active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
    border: 1px solid rgb(154, 215, 255);
  }
  /* Fading animation */
  .fade {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  @keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;"  class="slideshow-container"> 
                            @foreach ($media_galleries as $media_gallery) 
                            <div class="mySlides fade">
                                @if($media_gallery->type == 1)   
                                    <img class="w-full h-full" src="/storage/death-gallery-media/{{ $media_gallery->media }}" />
                                @endif
                                @if($media_gallery->type == 2)    
                                    <video class="w-full h-full" id="video{{$media_gallery->id}}" controls>
                                        <source src="/storage/death-gallery-media/{{ $media_gallery->media }}" alt="" type="video/mp4">
                                        
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                    </video>                                                         
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
                                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1); document.getElementById('video{{$media_gallery->id}}').pause();">&#10094;</a>
                                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1); document.getElementById('video{{$media_gallery->id}}').pause();">&#10095;</a>
                            @endforeach
                            <!-- Dots buttons -->
                            <div style="position:absolute; z-index:999; top:0; right:43%;">
                                @php
                                    $a=1;
                                @endphp
                                @foreach ($media_galleries as $media_gallery) 
                                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide({{$a}})"></span>                                
                                    @php
                                        $a++
                                    @endphp
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258871/pause-video-on-slider) puede que te ayude en tu duda.